# Delaying not preventing Bash function from simultaneous execution

Tags: linux, bash

I need to block the simultaneous calling of `highCpuFunction` function. I have tried to create a blocking mechanism, but it is not working. How can I do this?

```
nameOftheScript="$(basename $0)"
pidOftheScript="$$"

highCpuFunction()
{
    # Function with code causing high CPU usage. Like tar, zip, etc.

    while [  -f /tmp/"$nameOftheScript"*  ];
    do
        sleep 5;
    done
    touch /tmp/"$nameOftheScript"_"$pidOftheScript"

    echo "$(date +%s) I am a Bad function you do not want to call me simultaniously..."
    # Real high CPU usage code for reaching the database and
    # parsing logs. It takes the heck out of the CPU.

    rm -rf /tmp/"$nameOftheScript"_"$pidOftheScript" 2>/dev/null
}

while true
do
   sleep 2
    highCpuFunction
done

# The rest of the code...
```

In short, I want to run `highCpuFunction` at least with a gap of 5 seconds. Regardless of the instance/user/terminal. I need to allow other users to run this function but in proper sequence and with a gap of at least 5 seconds.

Comment: There are a number questions and answers about locking mechanisms in Bash in SO. [Here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex) is another resource.

Comment: they are for preventing the other executions, I need to delay second execution till first is completed.

Comment: Could you maybe invert the order into something like `while (!tryLock()) { sleep(1); }; doCpuIntensiveTask(); sleep(5); unlock();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `flock` tool. Consider this code (let's call it 'onlyoneofme.sh'):

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 9>/var/lock/myexclusivelock

flock 9
echo start
sleep 10
echo stop
```

It will open file /var/lock/myexclusivelock as descriptor 9 and then try to lock it exclusively. Only one instance of the script will be allowed to pass behind the `flock 9` command. The rest of them will wait for the other script to finish (so the descriptor will be closed and the lock freed). After this, the next script will acquire the lock and execute, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In the following solution the `# rest of the script` part can be executed only by one process. The test and set is atomic, and there isn't any race condition, whereas `test -f file` .. `touch file`, two processes can touch the file.

```
try_acquire_lock() {
    local lock_file=$1
    # Noclobber option to fail if the file already exists
    # in a sub-shell to avoid modifying current shell options
    ( set -o noclobber; : >"$lock_file")
}

# Trap to remove the file when the process exits
trap 'rm "$lock_file"' EXIT

lock_file=/tmp/"$nameOftheScript"_"$pidOftheScript"
while ! try_acquire_lock "$lock_file";
do 
    echo "failed to acquire lock, sleeping 5sec.."
    sleep 5;
done

# The rest of the script
```

It's not optimal, because the wait is done in a loop with sleep. To improve, one can use inter process communication (FIFO), or operating system notifications or signals.

```
# Block current shell process
kill -STOP $BASHPID

# Unblock blocked shell process (where <pid> is the id of the blocked process)
kill -CONT <pid>
```